# Updating point-in-time (bitemporal) table

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Let's have a table storing point-in-time (bitemporal) data:

```
pit:([]dt:`date$();sym:`symbol$();val:`float$();stamp:`timestamp$())
```

Sample data might look like:

```
`pit insert (2015.01.05 2015.01.06 2015.01.05;`IBM`IBM`MSFT;105.11 106.6 35.3; 2015.02.01D05:01:25.0 2015.02.01D05:01:25.0 2015.02.01D05:01:25.0)
pit
dt         sym  val    stamp                        
----------------------------------------------------
2015.01.05 IBM  105.11 2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
2015.01.06 IBM  106.6  2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
2015.01.05 MSFT 35.3   2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
```

For example, on the `stamp` point in time, we've recorded for `IBM` symbol a value of 105.11 valid for `2015.01.05`

There are new data coming in continuously and some of them are to be inserted as new records into the `pit` table, but only if they convey new information. No existing records in `pit` may be deleted nor updated/overwritten. I.e. we want to keep track of outdated (if any) values for auditing or authenticity purposes. Think of earnings estimate updates over time.

For example, later on we might receive:

```
new:([]dt:`date$();sym:`symbol$();val:`float$())
`new insert (2015.01.05 2015.01.06;`IBM`IBM;105.22 106.6)
new
dt         sym val   
---------------------
2015.01.05 IBM 105.22
2015.01.06 IBM 106.6
```

After incorporating `new` information into `pit`, the latter shall look like:

```
pit
dt         sym  val    stamp                        
----------------------------------------------------
2015.01.05 IBM  105.11 2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
2015.01.05 IBM  105.22 2015.03.10D15:43:50.000000000
2015.01.06 IBM  106.6  2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
2015.01.05 MSFT 35.3   2015.02.01D05:01:25.000000000
```

Note the "new" `105.22` value for `IBM` symbol entered the `pit` with the current timestamp (`2015.03.10D15:43:50` at the time of writing). Also, the `106.6` value from `new` did not update the timestamp in the `pit` in any way, because we had had that value already reflected in the `pit` carrying older timestamp.

How to write the respective `insert` statements using `q`?

Note: For what it's worth, `pit` is to be partitioned by additional column `source` not shown here for the sake of simplicity. Also, partitions will have `` `g#sym ``(possibly `` `p#sym `` instead) and `` `s#dt `` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'upsert' in following way:

reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#upsert

Step 1. I am adding status column in 'new' table (otherwise it will be null for new rows in final table)

```
       q) new:update stamp:`timestamp$.z.z from new
```

Step 2. Make those columns of 'new' as primary keys whose modification is criteria for addition of row. In your case it's all columns  except stamp column.

```
       q)new:except[cols new;`stamp] xkey new
```

Step 3:  Upsert tables as (check the order: pit is on right hand side)

```
       q) pit: 0!new upsert pit
```

I have removed primary keys  attribute from result.

Step 4: Order the table according to stamp (or any other column).

```
       q) pit: `stamp xasc pit
```

Here is one function to do all those steps:

```
    q) myinsert:{[pit;new] `stamp xasc 0!(except[cols new;`stamp] xkey new:update stamp:`timestamp$.z.z from new) upsert pit}
```

Comment: Nice! I was obviously looking at `upsert`, but in wrong order: `pit upsert new` instead of `new upsert pit`. I was under false impression that from the documentation syntax `r:table upsert new_records` , the argument `new_records` is actually my `new` table. Thanks!

Comment: I am now wondering whether upserting the whole, potentially very big `pit` table to the fractional `new` table, will create significant performance/memory issues. But that's a separate topic

Comment: One question: why does `pit myinsert new` not work while `myinsert[pit;new]` does? Could I make the first syntax work somehow?

Comment: 'pit insert new ' uses infix form which is  applicable to  kdb inbuilt functions. myinsert is user defined function  which should be called as normal function call.  Following site suggests one way to use it as infix form : http://www.kdbfaq.com/kdb-faq/how-can-i-define-my-own-infix-functions.html

Comment: @Daniel You are right about performance issue in case of very big pit table. Have to consider other solution in case of tight memory/cpu situation.